# switch statements in swift using buttons

Tags: swift

i cant figure out how to use my switch statement in swift so that when i click either button it will execute the println(). each time i click either button it just executes the default.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    var addOne : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
    var addFive : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        addOne.setTitle("+1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        addOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        addOne.center = (CGPointMake(40, 250))
        addOne.addTarget(self, action: "player", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(addOne)

        addFive.setTitle("+5", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        addFive.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        addFive.center = (CGPointMake(200, 250))
        addFive.addTarget(self, action: "player", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(addFive)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func player(){

        switch (true){

        case addOne:
            println("goodbye")
        case addFive:
            println("hello world")

        default:
            println("hello")
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change This:

```
addOne.addTarget(self, action: "player", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

To This:

```
addOne.addTarget(self, action: "player:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

And This:

```
addFive.addTarget(self, action: "player", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

To This:

```
addFive.addTarget(self, action: "player:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Note the addition of the colon in "player:"

Next, change This:

```
func player(){

    switch (true){

    case addOne:
        println("goodbye")
    case addFive:
        println("hello world")

    default:
        println("hello")
    }

}
```

To This:

```
func player(sender: UIButton){

    switch (sender){

    case addOne:
        println("goodbye")
    case addFive:
        println("hello world")

    default:
        println("hello")
    }

}
```

Comment: why does adding the semicolons affect how my switch statement work?

Comment: The semicolon indicates that the selector takes an argument.  In the case of a button, this means that it will send itsself as the argument.  Previously, your switch argument was `true`.  Because you were trying to compare buttons to `true`, none of your case's evaluated to `true`.  By passing the button as an argument, we can properly compare your button properties to the button that triggered the action.

Answer (score 0):

Use switch-case statement for applying different states of player with using of UIButton Action.

```
// --------------------------------------------------------
// MARK:- UIButton Action
// --------------------------------------------------------

@IBAction func onTapPauseBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    
    switch self.player.playbackState {
    case .stopped:
        self.player.playFromBeginning()
        break
    case .paused:
        self.player.playFromCurrentTime()
        btnPause.setImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .normal)
        break
    case .playing:
        self.player.pause()
        btnPause.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_play_video"), for: .normal)
        break
    case .failed:
        self.player.pause()
        break
    }
}
```